# Python variable visibility

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
def main():
    range_dur = 0
    xrange_dur = 0

    def do_range():
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(2,10):
            print i
        range_dur += time.time() - start              <---- cant see
    def do_xrange():
        start = time.time()
        for i in xrange(2,10):
            print i
        xrange_dur += time.time() - start             <---- cant see

    do_range()
    do_xrange()
    print range_dur
    print xrange_dur

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know I could put `range_dur` and `xrange_dur` outside of main() and have them called global inside `do_range()` and `do_xrange()` to be seen but how come the above doesnt work?

Whats the inner-working of variable visibility for python?

or is there another solution besides using it as global?

Comment: Alternately you could pass them as parameters to the corresponding function and get computation as `return` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, see [pandubear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336999/298479) - `nonlocal` is the way to go.

If you are using Python 2 you need to use a workaround based on mutable objects so you avoid the rebinding caused by `+=`. The easiest way to do this is wrapping the value in a list:

```
def main():
    range_dur = [0]
    xrange_dur = [0]

    def do_range():
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(2,10):
            print i
        range_dur[0] += time.time() - start

    def do_xrange():
        start = time.time()
        for i in xrange(2,10):
            print i
        xrange_dur[0] += time.time() - start             

    do_range()
    do_xrange()
    print range_dur[0]
    print xrange_dur[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another option - at least for a super-simple benchmark script like yours - would be using global variables. Then you can use `global` instead of `nonlocal`. It's not pretty but for a benchmark prettiness does not really matter.

The **best** solution however is simply using `return` to return the result!

Oh, and did you know about the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module? It does what you are trying to do; just in a nicer way.

Comment: python is purposely designed this way to limit programmers to pass param around? ah awesome timeit module

Comment: Rather than using a list to wrap the values I like to use a class (named `nonlocal` so you know it's serving the same purpose as `nonlocal` in Python 3).  Then you can access `nonlocal.x` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can see those variables, -- that is, get their values -- but you can't set their values without using a nonlocal statement. Use this:

```
def main():
    range_dur = 0
    xrange_dur = 0

    def do_range():
        nonlocal range_dur
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(2,10):
            print i
        range_dur += time.time() - start
    def do_xrange():
        nonlocal xrange_dur
        start = time.time()
        for i in xrange(2,10):
            print i
        xrange_dur += time.time() - start             

    do_range()
    do_xrange()
    print range_dur
    print xrange_dur

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @ealeon Replace `nonlocal` with `global`

Comment: @SethMMorton only if i put range_dur and xrange_dur outside of main

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to pass `range_dur` and `xrange_dur` as parameters to the functions, and return values from those functions?